# Need to run GET type operations on a string. Regex?

Tags: php, regex, post, get, base64

am working on some API stuff. I can pass some GET data "opt" to an application and on save in the application, the data "opt" is returned in POST. All good.

I need to pass more data to this api and I want to secure it slightly, so I have built a string containing several parts and encoded into base64.

unencoded string would look like this `sec_key=xxxxx&url=../dffd/dfg/dfg.jpg&key=xxxxxx`

if needed I can easily change that to:

```
sec_key=xxxxx&amp;url=../dffd/dfg/dfg.jpg&amp;key=xxxxxx
```

on save in the API app, I receive my encoded string back, then decode - all good.

Question is, I would usually use $_GET to strip out each data part. Can I use $_GET in some way to read from a $string rather than the url?

or do I need some regex and preg_match?. If so, whats the regex to mimic $_GET data extraction..

Comment: Do you know that base64 is not encryption? It doesn't make your program more secure!!!!! It is an encoding for the transportation layer, allowing to transport anything as ASCII string, if a protocol needs that (like email attachments). Encrypting is only one possible goal of encoding. What you want is encryption. Sending everything as POST with HTTPS would be the most easy way to get at least some security. Also if you encrypt anything and send the key in the same message, that is like buying an expensive lock for your apartment door and leaving the key in the lock (on the outside).

Comment: yes, I know. The sec_key name in this case is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract some data from a string that contains something that looks like a query string, you'll want to take a look at [**`parse_str()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

For example, the following portion of code :

```
$string = 'sec_key=xxxxx&url=../dffd/dfg/dfg.jpg&key=xxxxxx';
parse_str($string, $data);
var_dump($data);
```

Would get you :

```
array
  'sec_key' => string 'xxxxx' (length=5)
  'url' => string '../dffd/dfg/dfg.jpg' (length=19)
  'key' => string 'xxxxxx' (length=6)
```

If needed, you could also use `$_GET` instead of `$data`, when calling `parse_str()`.

It doesn't look like quite a good practice... But it'll work.

Comment: Brilliant, Learnt a new function. Thank you!